# Is it possible to send redirect without call response.sendRedirect(...) method?

Tags: java, servlets

In servlet, i want the client browser to redirect to a new URL, the `response` object has been set header with `Location` to a new url by the lib, but i can't get the redirect url in my code(no response.getHeader(...), so my question is, Is it possible to send redirect without call response.sendRedirect(...) method? How?

Comment: NO, the redirect url is not the same with `request.getRequestURL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your `HttpServletResponse`'s status code to 302 and the `Location` header to the URI you want

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY); // or SC_FOUND
response.setHeader("Location", "some uri");
```

Comment: @July I still don't understand why you can't use `sendRedirect`, but you are welcome.

Comment: As I said in my question, the redirect url is set by a low level lib, i can not modify the lib, and can not get the head from response.getHeader(...)(no such method).

Comment: @july [`HttpServletResponse` does have such a method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

You can send the redirect in the response body instead.

something like...

```
response.getWriter().println("<html><head><META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://google.com\"></head></html>\");
```

Comment: Well i have said i can't get the redirect url... but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes. That confused me because it didn't seem related to the question, which was how to redirect the client without calling sendRedirect().